# Prove that $\psi(s) = - \gamma - \frac{1}{s} - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{s+n} - \frac{1}{n})$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have $\psi (s) = \frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)}$. I need to prove that $\psi(s) = - \gamma - \frac{1}{s} - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{s+n} - \frac{1}{n})$. Then I tried to use Wierstrass' formula. I have $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} = se^{\gamma s} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{s}{n}) e^{-\frac{s}{n}}$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

 Then I also have $$\Gamma'(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} (\log(t))t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$Then I multiply $\Gamma'(s)$ and $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$. And I get $$\frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)} = se^{\gamma s} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{s}{n}) e^{-\frac{s}{n}} (\int_{0}^{\infty} (\log(t))t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt)$$
 But I'm stuck on how to get my desired equation. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks so much!
 **SOLUTION:** According to the Weierstrass' formula, we have $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} = se^{\gamma s} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}((1+\frac{s}{n})e^{-\frac{s}{n}})$$where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
Then I take logarithm on both sides, and I have $$\log(\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}) = \log(se^{\gamma s}\prod_{n= 1}^{\infty}((1+\frac{s}{n})e^{-\frac{s}{n}}))$$Then since $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} = (\Gamma(s))^{-1}$, then we have $$-\log(\Gamma(s)) = \log(se^{\gamma s}\prod_{n= 1}^{\infty}((1+\frac{s}{n})e^{-\frac{s}{n}}))$$Then we have \begin{align} \log(\Gamma(s)) & = -\log(se^{\gamma s}\prod_{n= 1}^{\infty}((1+\frac{s}{n})e^{-\frac{s}{n}})) \\ & = -[\log(se^{\gamma s}) + \log(\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1 + \frac{s}{n})e^{-\frac{s}{n}})] \\& = -[\log(s) + \gamma s + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\log((1+\frac{s}{n})e^{-\frac{s}{n}})] \\ & = -[\log(s) = \gamma s + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (log(1 + \frac{s}{n}) - \frac{s}{n})]\end{align} Then we differentiate both sides, and we get \begin{align}\frac{d}{ds} [log(\Gamma(s))] & = -\frac{1}{s} = \gamma + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{n}{n+s} - \frac{1}{n}) \\ & = -\frac{1}{s} + \gamma + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n+s} - \frac{1}{n})\end{align} Since $\frac{d}{ds} [\log(\Gamma(s))] = \frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)}$, then we have $$\frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)} = -\frac{1}{s} + \gamma + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n+s} - \frac{1}{n})$$

Comment: Simply take the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass formula for the gamma function and that will get the job done - that's how diagamma is defined. Products becomes sums, etc... when you take log, then differentiate. The theorem that allows this is here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Logarithmic_Derivative_of_Infinite_Product_of_Analytic_Functions

Comment: @Integralfan Thank you for your answers and hints!! I've continued after your solution and updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note
$$\log(\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}) = \log(se^{\gamma s} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{s}{n}) e^{-\frac{s}{n}})$$
is
$$-\log(\Gamma(s)) = \log(se^{\gamma s}) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log\big((1+\frac{s}{n})e^{-\frac{s}{n}} \big)$$
which is also
$$-\log(\Gamma(s)) = \log(s)+\gamma s + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \big[\log(1+\frac{s}{n})-\frac{s}{n} \big]$$
Now I leave it to you to just differentiate and multiply by negative one.

Note, such a manipulation can always be done on functions defined as infinite products of analytic functions, given that the product converges uniformly locally (or on compact sets). This condition gives the analyticity needed to differentiate. Weierstrass factorizations are the most famous (and probably motivating) example.